# How do I display an undefined number of divs inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline

I need to display all my divs in one line, but I don't know necessarily have the number of divs in the page since I have a button that enables adding more divs.
I want to be able to add div in the same line until there's no more place and then the rest will be added to in the next line and so on.
all my divs have the same class name.

Comment: Do you know the size of the divs. Are they all the same size?

Comment: Are the divs with fixed width?

Comment: yes I've specified the size of the divs to be the same, and each line fits the same number of divs.

Comment: You can get the width of your page, and you know the width of your `div`s and therefore know how many will fit horizontally before requiring to start a newline. So what's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I know how many divs fit horizontally, but how do I require starting  anew line when I reach the right number?

Comment: this sounds like it would be solved by using CSS alone. Did you try `float: left`? This way, your divs will behave much like regular text does.

Comment: float: left works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block;` but if the added space between the elements bothers you, try floating all the `div` elements to the left or right and clear the container if necessary.

`div { float: left; }` or `div { float: right; }` depending on the ordering you're looking for and `.container { overflow: auto; }` as a clear-fix, assuming that you've assigned the `container` class to the containing element.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display:inline-block;` on divs so they atomaticaly start on a new line when there isn't enough space left :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ygN8M/)**